# How to read a tag with two attributes

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have an xml rss with a special tag I do not know how to read the second part, in this case the subcategory

XML RSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel>
    <category text="Category">
    <category text="Subcategory"/>
    </category>
</channel>

</rss>
```

PHP

```
//this gives the category
$category = $feed->channel->category->attributes(); 
echo $category . '<br>';

//I tried this but only gives category and I need subcategory too
foreach ($feed->channel->category->attributes() as $item) { 
    echo $item . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have two category **elements**, not two **attributes**; and one category element is a nested element of the other category element

```
foreach ($feed->channel->category as $category) { 
    foreach($category->attributes() as $attribute) {
        echo $attribute . '<br>';
    }

    foreach ($category->category as $subcategory) { 
        foreach($subcategory->attributes() as $attribute) {
            echo $attribute . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

It might be easier to understand if your snippet was syntactically correct, **and** properly indented

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss>
    <channel>
        <category text="Category">
            <category text="Subcategory"/>
        </category>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

So a `category` element can have "child" elements, also called `category`

Comment: there is an { missing in the second foreach. I copy paste adding this and it does not work, it only gives the category

Comment: Just re-edited to allow for the nested category elements

Comment: It works, but I do not understand. Can you explain, please? If they are two elements why do you need to iterate to reach the first?

Comment: Now I understand, the key is that you indented well the rss. Now I see that it is not necessary to use the foreach. This works too and is more simple and clear:   
$subCategory = $feed->channel->category->category->attributes();
echo $subCategory;